# Manually Create Role in Serverless Instead of Serverless Creating It

Tags: serverless, amazon-iam, aws-serverless

Is there a way to manually create the role and put it in serverless.yml? The thing is, we are not given the "iam:CreateRole" permission in our iam user because of their security policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your serverless.yml can use an already existing IAM role.

You can set it at the provider level:

```
provider:
    role: <role ARN>
```

Or at role level:

```
functions:
     myFunction:
          role: <role ARN>
```